# Converting geoJson to shapfile as batch using GDAL ogr2ogr in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gdal, ogr2ogr

I want to convert all the geojsons in a file to shapefiles in a single batch using ogr2ogr library in NodeJS. I know it can be done directly from the terminal using the gdal cli, but I want do know how to do it in Node. Thanks alot!

I have this code to convert a single file:

```js
// Using CommonJS modules
const ogr2ogr = require('ogr2ogr').default;
const fs = require('fs') ;

// Promise API
(async() => {   

  // Convert path to GeoJSON.
  let {data} = await ogr2ogr('/Users/MihaiB/Desktop/test_josm/test22.geojson' );
  console.log(data);  
 
  let {stream} = await ogr2ogr( data, {format: 'ESRI Shapefile'}, {destination:'/Users/MihaiB/Desktop/shapefile2.shx'});
    console.log(stream)       
  
})()
```

Comment: So you already have discovered how to use `ogr2ogr` and what exact problem with it do you have? I see You have passed GeoJSON as input (you even can indicate a path instead of a concrete file) and  Shape file format as output.

Comment: hello @Anatoly ty for the reply, the code I added works fine, but what I'm asking is:
Does anyone know how to run the conversion as a batch? (for example I want to convert 10 geojson from a folder, without doing it individually)

Comment: But when you indicate a folder and not a certain file then ogr2ogr should process all files in this folder

Comment: Error: Command failed: ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -skipfailures /vsistdout/ /Users/MihaiB/Desktop/test_josm/JSONS
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `/Users/MihaiB/Desktop/test_josm/JSONS' with the following drivers.
  -> `BAG'
  -> `FITS'
  -> `netCDF'  

this is what I get when I point to a folder instead of a file

Comment: It seems it doesn't support multifile processing so you need to read a file list of a directory and process it either sequentially or in parallel by calling ogr2ogr for each file,

Comment: ty very much for your suggestion, any idea how would I implement that. I'm a little stuck to be totally honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, the solution seemed to be pretty easy (even if it took way to long to figure it out) I had to use dirTree package to get the paths for all the files in a given folder

```
const ogr2ogr = require('ogr2ogr').default;
const PATH = require('path');
const dirTree = require('directory-tree');

  // Promise API
( async() => {
  
  // List Files in a Directory using dirTree package
  const tree = dirTree('/Users/MihaiB/Desktop/test_josm/', {extensions:/\.geojson$/}, 
  
  async (item, PATH, stats) => {
  console.log(PATH);
        
  // Convert path to GeoJSON
  let {data} = await ogr2ogr(PATH);
  console.log(data);

  // Convert GeoJSON to Shapefile
  let {stream} = await ogr2ogr( data, {format: 'ESRI Shapefile', destination:'/Users/MihaiB/Desktop/batch2/'});
  console.log(stream)

 }); 
})
()
```